# Tableviewcell calling uiview controller function not working swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   cell.viewcontroller = self
}

func reloadData(){
    // reload function here, so when called it will reload the tableView
    self.notificationTable.reloadData()
}
```

Tableview cell button code

```
@IBAction func deleteRecord(_ sender: Any) {
    self.viewController.reloadData() //<-- 
}
```

Getting error

> @ <--
>
> NotificationTableViewCell.swift:64:18: Value of type
>   'UIViewController' has no member 'reloadData'

Comment: in here `self.viewController.reloadData()` use your tableview name `self. notificationTable.reloadData()`

Comment: why you are deleteRecord() declared in  tableViewCell  ?

Comment: did you check max's answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `(self.viewController as? YourViewControllerClass).reloadData()`. `UIViewController` doesn't have `reloadData()` method - only your subclass does.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call reload method using NSNotificationCenter

// Declare in your ViewController's ViewDidLoad

```
// Register to receive notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName. reloadData), name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

In TableViewCell

```
@IBAction func deleteRecord(_ sender: Any) {
        // Post notification
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
}
```